# How to assign a value to a variable in TensorFlow properly?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have created a logistic classification model written in TensorFlow. Now I need to manually set values of the model parameters and generate some predictions. This is what I do:

```
# instantiate the model
lr = logreg(inp_dim = 4, out_dim = 3)

# generate model parameters
w = np.array([
    [ 1.0,  2.0,  3.0],
    [ 4.0,  5.0,  6.0],
    [ 7.0,  8.0,  9.0],
    [10.0, 11.0, 12.0]
    ])
b = np.array([13.0, 14.0, 15.0])

# assign the values to the model
lr.w = tf.assign(lr.w, w)
lr.b = tf.assign(lr.b, b)
```

Apparently, it is not enough. The model still uses the old parameters (that have been randomly generate when the model was instantiated). So, I need to do the following additional steps:

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
s = tf.Session()
s.run(init)
```

I though that after that step the model should use the new values of the parameters (since I have initialized all the global variables). However, it is not the case. The model starts to see the new values of the parameters only if I execute the following additional commands:

```
s.run(lr.w)
s.run(lr.b)
```

So, in fact I have managed to achieve what I wanted but, first, I do not have a clear picture of what is happening and, second, I am not sure that it was a proper way to set the values of the model parameters.

Could someone please explain the logic behind the setting values to the model variables in TensorFlow?

**ADDED:**

After I execute assign I need to execute run. Only this way the variable will get its value. For example:

```
w = tf.assign(w, 3.0)
sess.run(w)
```

But why the same logic is not applicable if I want a variable to get its value that has been given at instantiation. For example if I execute

```
w = tf.Variable(3.0, tf.float32)
```

The variable will not get its value. I would think that to solve this problem I would do the same trick as before (`sess.run(w)`). But it is not the case, I need to execute the following magic commands:

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when you run `s.run(init)` you only run the initializer op in your graph and its parents but absolutely nothing else. As a matter of fact `lr.w` is not a parent of the `init` op so TensorFlow won't run it and therefore you have to run it manually as you did.

Edit: 
I meant the [TensorFlow graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph) which holds all the variables and operations you defined (in your case the one in the `logreg` method + the 2 assigns you added).

The `init = tf.global_variables_initializer()` op only initialize the variables and doesn't run any other operations (and in particular the assign operations you define later).

Comment: what "graph" do you mean? To me it looks like I need to execute `s.run(init)` to properly assign the values that have been specified at instantiation of the variables (for more details you can check the extension of my question).

Comment: Assign is an op.  You must execute that op to assign the new value.